# Plotly: creating charts using Excel data; Attribute Error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plotly

Sorry if it's  a silly question, I'm a newbie.
I'm trying to make a chart in plotly from data in Excel. I don't know how to import data from an Excel sheet, whatever I tried ended up in the same error.
I would be thankful for any tips!
[Attribute Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwfNe.png)

This is the code that ended up in Error showed above.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
kleb = pd.read_excel("/content/skrzypce_k_bufory.xlsx")
df = px.data.kleb()
fig = px.violin(df, y="% coverage", color="Amount", violinmode='overlay', hover_data=kleb.columns)
fig.show()
```

I tried introducing data using `df = px.data.kleb()`

But it doesn't work, probably for a very good reason, but I'm too much of a beginner to figure it out. Is there a way to insert a path into this command or using panda so it works for plotly?

Comment: can u show us the data or a snippet of it?

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory, the [`px.data`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.data.html) module, which provides some datasets, has no kleb() function. You want to load _your_ dataset, [`pd.read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) returns a dataframe, so `df = pd.read_excel("/content/skrzypce_k_bufory.xlsx")` then use that df to build the figure.